# 404 Error from Web Forms When Posting to Web API Controller

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, asp.net-web-api, webforms

I am unable to post form data from an ASP.NET Web form to my Web API controller because I keep getting a 404 or 'Not found' error.

Here is the code in my **Global.asax.vb** file:

```
Imports System.Web.Optimization
Imports System.Web.Http

Public Class Global_asax
    Inherits HttpApplication

    Sub Application_Start(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        ' Fires when the application is started
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles)

        RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}", New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional})

    End Sub
End Class
```

This is the AJAX in the Web Form:

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'api/UserApi',
                data: $('form').serialize(),
                success: function(response) {
                    var result = JSON.parse(response);
                    if (result.validationError) {
                        $('.jumbotron').prepend('<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Make sure to fill in all fields.</strong></div>');

                        if ($('.alert-danger').length > 1) {
                            $('.alert-danger').last().remove();
                        }
                    }
                    else if (result.error) {
                        $('.jumbotron').prepend('<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>User with that email address already exists!</strong></div>');

                        if ($('.alert-danger').length > 1) {
                            $('.alert-danger').last().remove();
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        if ($('.alert-danger').is(':visible')) {
                            $('.alert-danger').remove();
                        }
                        $('.jumbotron h1').remove();
                        $('form').replaceWith('<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>User created successfully!</strong></div>');
                    }
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
```

Lastly, this is the code in the Web API controller:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Web.Http
Imports System.Web.Http.Results

<RoutePrefix("api/UserApi")>
Public Class UserApiController
    Inherits ApiController

    ' POST api/<controller>
    Public Sub PostValue(<FromBody()> ByVal email As String, name As String)
        Dim user = New User With {
            .Email = email,
            .Name = name
        }

        Dim userDbContext = New UserDBContext()
        userDbContext.Users.Add(user)

    End Sub

End Class
```

The controller is called "**UserApiController.vb**" and it is in the main directory of the project. I've tried putting the exact same routing in the **RouteConfig.vb** file in the **App_Start** directory as well as using the annotation for routing you see above my class declaration in my controller, and still no luck. Also, I've written the route as `RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{action}/{id}", New With {.controller = "UserApi", .id = RouteParameter.Optional})` and posting to the url api/PostValue in AJAX.

Comment: Is there an app_code directory in vb? the controller should be in there. What is the exact directory of the .aspx page?

Comment: @wazz there is no app_code directory and the .aspx file is in the main directory of the project.

Comment: I'm pretty new to web api and have only set up a simple get. That's all i can suggest - set up a simple getJson until the 'not found' problem is sorted. `$.getJSON("api/helloworld", function (data) { ...`.

Comment: @wazz Thank you. I’ve put the controller in the suggested app_code folder and now I’m getting 500 error instead of a 404. Now I just have to figure out what the error is.

Comment: Windows logs can help with 500s, if you have access. Start > type 'event viewer'.

Comment: @wazz From looking at the HTTPER log file and Event Viewer, I found out it is a 503 error and now, Event Viewer says "The directory specified for caching compressed content C:\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files\Clr4IntegratedAppPool is invalid.  Static compression is being disabled." I'm not really sure how to fix this issue. All the solutions I find are for IIS on Windows Server and not IIS Express.

Comment: @wazz Also, since this question is about getting a 404 error, and I solved the 404 by adding my code to the App_Code folder, you should post that as an answer, and I will accept it as the best answer.

Comment: Thanks, I added an answer. I recently saw that error too and I don't think it really matters, at least for the current problem. Wouldn't hurt to restart IIS and VS at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your controller is in the ASP.NET folder called App_Code.

```
Right-click website (or sim)
> Add
> Add ASP.NET Folder
> App_Code
```

All .cs code should be in there. (Not pages' code-behind files.)