# 503 Error from Clr4IntegratedAppPool When Posting using ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, webforms

I am trying to POST from a .aspx file in Web Forms and using network tracking in my browser, I get back a 500 error. Visual Studio 2017 doesn't give me any errors, so when I go to Event Viewer on Windows 7, I see that it keeps giving me the warning:

> The directory specified for caching compressed content
>   C:\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files\Clr4IntegratedAppPool
>   is invalid.  Static compression is being disabled.

Another error I found is from the HTTPER log file. That doesn't always produce an error, but when it does, it says:

> Connection_Abandoned_By_ReqQueue Clr4IntegratedAppPool

Or simply, just **503**.

My solution is using .NET 4.6.1 and I've tried changing the version in `<add name="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Integrated" CLRConfigFile="%IIS_USER_HOME%\config\aspnet.config" autoStart="true" />` from 4.0 to 4.0.30319. Does anyone know if .NET 4.6 uses a different version for Clr4IntegratedAppPool?

The response body received by the browser says:

> An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Multiple types were found
>   that match the controller named 'UserApi'. This can happen if the
>   route that services this request ('api/{action}/{id}') found multiple
>   controllers defined with the same name but differing namespaces, which
>   is not supported.The request for 'UserApi' has found the
>   following matching
>   controllers:UserApiController Application.UserApiController","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":"
>   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector.SelectController(HttpRequestMessage
>   request)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"

I've done lots of research online, and most of the solutions are for IIS on Windows server and not IIS Express.

Lastly, if you'd like to see my code, it is posted in my previous, [solved question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50217646/404-error-from-web-forms-when-posting-to-web-api-controller).

Comment: What’s the response body of the 500 error?

Comment: @LexLi I've updated my question with the response body.